# Return Only Certain Fields From Lucene Search

Tags: search, lucene, lucene.net

I'm using Lucene to search an index and it works fine.  My only issue is that I only need one particular field of what is being returned.  Can you specify to Lucene to only return a certain field in the results and not the entire document?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is why [`FieldSelector`](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_9_3/api/all/org/apache/lucene/document/FieldSelector.html) class exists.
You can implement  a class like this

```cs
class MyFieldSelector : FieldSelector
{
    public FieldSelectorResult Accept(string fieldName)
    {
        if (fieldName == "field1") return FieldSelectorResult.LOAD_AND_BREAK;
        return FieldSelectorResult.NO_LOAD;
    }
}
```

and use it as `indexReader.Document(docid,new MyFieldSelector());`

If you are interested in loading a *small* field, this will prevent to load *large* fields which, in turn, means a speed-up in loading documents. I think you can find much more detailed info by some googling.

Answer (score -2):

What do you mean "return certain fields"? The [Document.get()](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_2/api/all/org/apache/lucene/document/Document.html#get%28java.lang.String%29) function returns just the field you request.

Comment: That's what I'm using now, but I only need one field so I was just wondering if there was a way to only return that field instead of the whole document.

Comment: @aaron: I'm still not certain what you mean by "return." The resulting text from `Document.get` is just the text of that one field. If you mean you don't want to store the values of other fields, simply mark them as not stored.

Comment: -1 but `reader.Document` loads whole document, not just a single field

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you can definitely do what you are asking. All you have to do is include the field name (case-sensitive) in the document.get() method.

```cs
string fieldNameText = doc.Get("fieldName");
```

FYI, it's usually a good idea to include some code in your questions. It makes it easier to provide a good answer.

Comment: I get what you're saying and that's what I'm doing now.  I'm trying to limit what fields are included in the doc.

Comment: You didnt ask how to limit which fields are included in the doc. You asked how to return a certain field in the results. Im not sure you're aaking the right question.

Comment: @SharpBarb, `You asked how to return a certain field in the results. Im not sure you're aaking the right question` Please read the question again after reading my answer. I think I will make sense then